# Rotate object around player with mouse but have it still comply with physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

In my game I want the character to be able to have a pickaxe or weapon that can rotate around the player but when I do so it goes through the objects and is very glitchy.

I want it to still follow the mouse (which is invisible) and still stop when it has a collision. My code right now is just pretty standard code for mouse rotation and its attached to an empty gameobject which is the parent of the pickaxe/weapon

```
//rotation
Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
mousePos.z = 5.23f;

Vector3 objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle));
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a GameObject that you want to be physics enabled, you don't move it directly. You add a [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) and use [RigidBody.MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) to rotate your GameObject. `RigidBody` has its set of movement and rotation methods that take into account collisions. Moving the `Transform` directly will cause problems.

This can *still* cause problems in some situations. If you're still experiencing physics weirdness then you can eliminate them by using a "physically correct" solution and use [Rigidbody.angularVelocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html). Based on the angle you can set the velocity to either rotate the object right or left until it faces the way you want.

Essentially the physics system hates teleportation. Instant movements and instant rotations are basically teleportation to it. So there's a hierarchy of how "physics system friendly" some actions are. And they go like this:

1. Adding Force to the RigidBody
2. Adding Velocity to the RigidBody
3. Moving the GameObject through appropriate RigidBody methods.
4. Moving the GameObject through Transform.